# dynamic vector-like container but whose elements save their indexes?

Tags: c++, containers

All the elements should have fixed position in the array after insertion until I explicitly delete them from there. Is there something like this in boost or wherever? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed position?"  Unless you insert or remove elements from the beginning or middle of a vector, the indices of its elements do not change.

Comment: @James McNellis: I mean that when I insert or remove _any_ element this should not affect on others' position. E.g if I have a container with 500 elements and I removed all first 499, the last should be 500th anyway and container's size should not change aswell.

Comment: @serejko:  Ok.  Just don't add or remove objects from the middle then, or, instead of adding or removing objects from the middle, replace them with default constructed objects or with some sentinel value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `unordered_map<int, T>` or `map<int, T>`.

Or, use a `vector<`[`optional<T>`](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)`>`, and set the slot to delete to `none_t`, instead of actually deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "deleting" an element, you want to set its value to null (or some other "no value" equivalent). Then everything stays constant as you require.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Is your goal is to expose a mapping from integers to SLOTS, where those SLOTS may contain a value?  Or is your goal to preserve the underlying address of each element and the underlying address of the start of the internal array itself? Presumably you have a reason that you need either the position of the elements or the mapping from integer keys to elements to be preserved after an element is "removed". What is that reason?

The `map<>` or `vector<>` implementations mentioned above may not work because the `remove`, `erase`, `find`, etc. operations will remove, rearrange, or inspect the integers which you consider to be "removed".

Unfortunately, I think this may be a case where you need to roll your own using a wrapper around `vector<optional<T> >` or `vector<T*>`, depending upon how you define `remove`.